# FTP script loops until stopped with control-c

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I've been trying to make an automated batch script to download a specific file from my FTP and then close the connection, but I've run into an issue.

Running the commands from cmd.exe works fine. I have no issues with that at all. As soon as I try to run it in a batch file however, the FTP command becomes entirely useless.

```
ping -n 3 127.0.0.1>nul
ftp -s:ftpscript.txt
pause
```

That's the batch file I have. Instead of following the FTP information defined in ftpscript.txt, it acts as a file reset and causes the batch file to re-execute in the same window as if I had just opened it. The output I get is as follows:

```
F:\FileZilla FTP Client>ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 1>nul
F:\FileZilla FTP Client>FTP -s:ftpscript.txt
F:\FileZilla FTP Client>ping -n 3 127.0.0.1 1>nul
F:\FileZilla FTP Client>FTP -s:ftpscript.txt
```

That is repeated until I forcefully terminate the batch file using Crtl+c. I have no labels in the file, nor do I have any "GOTO" commands. The syntax is, to my understanding, correct but the file refuses to properly operate.

Anyone with either similar issues or a solution to this one? Atm, running directly from the command line is a bit tiring.
Thanks.
~BAI1

Comment: Don't call the batch script `ftp` or `ping`

Comment: Gonna test that. Probably was that coming to think of it, if it is then I'll be happy.

Comment: Alright that worked. I was a bit stupid in naming and such, corrected that now. Thanks (needs to know how to mark this as closed).

Comment: Good to hear it. You can delete your question if you like - as it's not an FTP issue.

Comment: I suggest that @foxidrive post his comment in an answer, and BAI1 select it as Best Answer. This method mark this question as "solved" (and the "<Resolved>" in the title should be removed). Perhaps a change in the title would be convenient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call the batch script `ftp` or `ping` or any command in your batch script,
as it will relaunch the batch script again and again.